# Recovering the covariance matrix of pixel coordinate from normalised camera coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, covariance, maximum-likelihood, computer-vision

lets assume we have the pixel value of some interest points as well as their covariance matrices that defined as follows:
$$ \mathbf x^{\prime} = 
       \begin{bmatrix}
        x^{\prime}\\
        y^{\prime}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
, \mathbf \Sigma_{x\prime x\prime} = 
       \begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma^2_{x^{\prime}} & \sigma_{x^{\prime} y^{\prime}}\\
        \sigma_{x^{\prime} y^{\prime}} & \sigma^2_{y^{\prime}} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
after that, pixel points convert to homogenous coordinate from Euclidean coordinate and are projected to the normalised camera coordinate by $K^{-1}$, where K represents the camera matrix.

$$
\mathbf x = K^{-1} \mathbf x^{\prime} =  \begin{bmatrix}
        x\\
        y\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
in the next step, we compute the covariance matrices for each new $\mathbf x$ point.
$$
\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x \mathbf x} = J_{\pi} \mathbf \Sigma_{x^{\prime} x^{\prime}} J_{\pi}^{T} = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma^2_{x} & \sigma_{x y} & 0\\
        \sigma_{x y} & \sigma^2_{y} & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $J_{\pi}$ is the jacobian of forward projection.
We also know the rank of matrix $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x \mathbf x}$ is 2 and it's singular and invertable. 
Next, we compute the normalised point $\mathbf x$ and we called it $\mathbf v$.
$$
\mathbf v = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        v_x\\
        v_y\\
        v_z\\
        \end{bmatrix} = \frac {\mathbf x}{\Vert \mathbf x \Vert},
        \mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf v \mathbf v} = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \sigma^2_{v_x} & \sigma_{v_{xv}} & \sigma_{v_{xz}} \\
        \sigma_{v_{xz}} & \sigma^2_{v_y} & \sigma_{v_{yz}} \\
        \sigma_{v_{zx}} & \sigma_{v_{zy}} & \sigma^2_{v_z}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
where 
$$
\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf v \mathbf v} = J \mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x \mathbf x} J^{T}, J = \frac{1}{\Vert \mathbf x \Vert}(\mathbf I_{3} - \mathbf v \mathbf v^{T})
$$
We also know the $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf v \mathbf v}$ remains invertable. From now, I can compute the rest procedure and update $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf v \mathbf v}$.
My main question is, after updating the $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf v \mathbf v}$, how can I update the $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x \mathbf x}$ and $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x^{\prime} \mathbf x^{\prime}}$ sequentially. In fact, the main difficult part of this job is extracting the $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x \mathbf x}$ from updated $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf v \mathbf v}$ while we should keep the rank of $\mathbf \Sigma_{\mathbf x \mathbf x}$, 2 and set the last column and row of that $0$ (similar to formula). 
It is noticeable, all equations, which I mentioned here, come from [MLPnP](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.08112.pdf) reference and here, I just summarised the equations 2-6.